# Access Windows VM command prompt from Mac OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, vmware, command-prompt

I have VMware Fusion 5 installed on my Mac, and have software installed on the Windows partition, that for various reasons, I would like to use via the Mac OSX Terminal rather than going through the VMware Fusion GUI of logging into my Windows VM and running command prompt and then running the software. I would prefer it if Terminal could access the windows command prompt of the vm machine, so that I can run the software from my Mac directly. I am happy to have them/would expect the Mac and Windows machines to be running side by side simultaneously.

Is this possible? I.e. can the Mac OSX Terminal access the VM Windows partition command prompt directly? And if so, how would one do this?

I had considered `ssh` but that seemed long-winded sending data backwards and forwards via the internet given that it is on a local machine and considered that there must be another/smarter alternative...also wasn't really sure it would work `ssh`'ing into from a Mac to Windows machine...

p.s. Sorry if SO isn't quite the right forum, and that there isn't quite a reproducible example, but have tried to explain the situation carefully to allow the community to help if possible. But if there is a better way to get a solution to my problem by either migrating or suggesting edits to the question that will make it a better question I would be more than happy to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vmrun` is the function that needs to be use used. I found it after a bit more searching...so the following will pretty much do the job...

```
/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun -T fusion -gu <user\ name> -gp <password> runProgramInGuest /Users/<hostUserName>/Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/Virtual\ Machines/Boot\ Camp/Boot\ Camp.vmwarevm/Boot\ Camp.vmx -interactive -noWait -activeWindow C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe C:\\testing.txt
```

This link is quite useful http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vix162_vmrun_command.pdf